# How to make a related field with two conditions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I need to make a related field with two other fields. Right according to my knowledge we can have only one. Is there is any other option?

I don't want a compute field. Because the field should be editable.

Comment: It is possible to make a computed field editable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267793/make-a-functional-field-editable-in-openerp/31268996#31268996

Comment: You can't and You should make two fields and hide one of them in the view. user will not notice that if the fields have the same label

Comment: Check the code of `standard_price` field in `product.template` model. You can make compute field editable by using `inverse` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Computed field can also editable fields make it readonly=False and make store true for it so that it relate to your two fields if you make any change in them it will reflect in your computed field and if not then you can put your value in that field and store that field data so it can save its value also.